# Openwhisk multitenancy on Openshift

Tags: openshift, multi-tenant, openwhisk

I'm trying to install Openwhisk onto Openshift. I've followed the official guide and it worked.

Now the point is that my environment would be a multitenant ecosystem, so let's pretend having two different users (Ux and Uy) who want to run their containers on my openwhisk environment.

I'd like to have the following projects in my openshift:

- *Core project*, that hosts the Openwhisk's **Ingress**, **Controller**, **Kafka** and **CouchDB** components (maybe also the Invokers?)
- *UxPRJ project*, that hosts only the containers running actions created by Ux (maybe also the Invokers?)
- *UyPRJ project*, that hosts only the containers running actions created by Uy (maybe also the Invokers?)

The following images better explain what I've in mind:

[image: Remote invokers]

or also:

[image]

Is this possible configuration possible?
Looking around, I wasn't able to find anything like that...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenWhisk loadbalancer which assigns functions to invokers does not segregate users in the way you want, but it is possible to do what you want if you modify the loadbalancer. The way it works now is that there is a list of available invokers which form the allowed set of invokers for a function assignment. You could at that point take into consideration a partitioning based on the user and form the allowed set of invokers differently. There are other ways to realize the partitioning you want as well, but all require modification to the OpenWhisk control plane.

Comment: Thank you. So you think that the only way is to have on entire openwhisk stack for each project?

Comment: Without modifying the loadbalancer, I think so. You can try emailing the project mailing list https://openwhisk.apache.org/community.html or opening a feature request on the project github repo https://github.com/apache/openwhisk/issues. If you were to deploy one stack per project, you may want to use an alternate stack, called the "lean" stack. Which fuses alll the microservices into one (controller, no kafka, invoker) and use an external Couch for sharing.